# Getting "Materialized view query contains unsupported feature." error while creating materialized view in BigQuery even with a simple query

Tags: google-bigquery

I am getting "**Materialized view query contains unsupported feature.**" error when I try to create a materialized view in the BigQuery even with a simple query.

I have read [this article](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/materialized-views-create#query_limitations) and understood the limitations that the BigQuery has in creating materialized views.

But the query I am trying doesn't seem to be falling under any of these limitations, yet I am getting unsupported feature error.

The query that I am trying:-

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW myproject.mydataset.my_mv_table AS (
  SELECT
    id
  FROM
    myproject.mydataset.my_base_table
    limit 100
);
```

I am expecting a simple materialized view to be created with this above query. But I am just getting the unsupported feature error which can be seen in the below image.

[image: Screenshot of query that I am trying & the error I am getting]

I am not getting what I am doing wrong.

Can someone help me to understand what I am doing wrong or what I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

`limit 100` is causing the issue as it is not supported in a materialized view. You can remove it as it doesn't reduce cost or performance.

Comment: I removed the limit and tried to create using the same query. But still, I am getting the unsupported feature error.
This time, the error has some more details (shown below)

`The materialized view query contains an unsupported feature. This may be caused by having an expression on top of the grouping keys or aggregated values.`

Comment: This is strange, as without the limit it should work. I'm guessing the issue is either in the source / destination or the way they are referenced to, but without seeing it, it'll be complicated to help further.